# How to see number of contracts on players in the Fifa 18 FUT web app

Tags: fifa-18

Does anyone know if it's possible to see the number of contracts players have in the FUT web app or companion app search results/squad overview?

I know it's possible to select a player and then change the view on the player details, but I'd like to be able to see at a glance when a player has a low or high number of contracts. It takes too long to click on each player to see how many contracts they have.

For example the small player card only shows the chemistry style. I'd love to be able to change that to show number of contracts instead so that it's visible on all players in a listing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way... kind of hidden, but it'll do I guess.

In the Companion App follow these steps:

1. Squads
2. Consumables
3. Contracts (quality doesn't matter)
4. Apply Consumable (you don't have to actually apply it)
5. Search (you can apply a filter, if necessary)
6. You'll now get a list of all players found with their remaining contract length + what would be added if you used that consumable:

[image: contracts list]